# copy a file from a local server to remote server without WINRM

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a file from my local server to a remote server without WINRM.The remote server has got credentials and is not in the local network or the local domain of my local server.
Do you have a solution ,please?

```
I have this error:
MethodInvocationException: D:\powershell\ip.ps1:23:1
Line |
  23 |  $WebClient.DownloadFile($Source, $Dest)
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."


Here is my code:


$Source = "C:\test10\test10.txt"
$Dest   = "\\public_ipadress_server\C:\test11\test10.txt"
$Username = "administrator"
$Password= convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String password
$MyIP = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
$MyIP | Out-File $Source 
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)

$WebClient.DownloadFile($Source, $Dest)
```

Comment: I cannot use WINRM because it's too difficult  to configure in my server and the remote server. I have already read this link, so I try another solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be possible to use standard UNC network copy?  I would consider mapping a drive to a share on your remote PC.  net use command will allow you to do this entering credentials for the remote computer.  Then you can copy the file over via the mapped drive.  I also added some code for providing the credentials in a more secure way.  It is not very good practice to store passwords in clear text which it appears you may be doing.

```
$source = "C:\test10\test10.txt"
$desiredMappedDrive = "J"
$desiredMappedDrivePath = "\\public_ipadress_server\C$" # Map to administrative C: drive share requires administrator credentials)
$destination   = "${desiredMappedDrive}:\test11\test10.txt"


$passwordFile = "C:\temp\encryptedCred"
if (-not (Test-Path $passwordFile) ) {
    $cred = Get-Credential
 
} else {
    $fileContents = Get-Content $passwordFile
    $userEncryptedString = $fileContents[0]
    $passEncryptedString = $fileContents[1]
    $userSecureString = $userEncryptedString | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $passSecureString = $passEncryptedString | ConvertTo-SecureString
    # convert secure string back to text
    $userString = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto( [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($userSecureString) ) 
    $cred = [pscredential]::new($userString, $passSecureString)
}

if ($cred) {
    $response = net use ${desiredMappedDrive}: $desiredMappedDrivePath /USER:$($cred.UserName) $($cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
    $response

    if ($response -match "command completed successfully") {
        $cred.UserName | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $passwordFile
        $cred.Password |ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -Append $passwordFile
        Write-Host "Credentials have been saved to $passwordFile.  While file exists you will not be asked to enter credentials for future script executions"
    }


    Copy-Item $source -Destination $destination
}
```