# How to use credentials in powershell script to copy file to a destination server?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to copy file from my local machine to a server destination

My Script:  `Copy-Item –Path D:\Test.txt –Destination '\\10.10.X.X\c$'`

Error:

```
Copy-Item : The network path was not found
At D:\PS_Test_script.ps1:1 char:2
+  Copy-Item –Path D:\Test.txt –Destination '\\10.10.X.28X\c$'
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

The server has credentials, I am guessing that, I have to invoke something to use the credentials.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65972741/11954025

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. Please give me idea of encryptedCred. What does it contain and in what format?

Comment: I think you would get a different message if the credentials are incorrect. Are you able to `ping` the ip address?

Comment: Yes, I am able to ping that @iRon

Comment: Do you have permission on C$ folder? try to test the copy on other folder  (Copy-Item -Path $Localbatch -Destination "\\10.10.X.X\share" -Force)

Comment: `$Credetial = get-credential; Copy-Item –Path D:\Test.txt –Destination '\\10.10.X.X\c$ -credential $Credential` (for username, use: `.\LocalUsernameOnServer`)

Comment: @iRon, still getting error: Copy-Item : The network path was not found

Comment: I think we have to do with a clasic PowerShell gotcha here: You using em-dashes for the parameters. Please, try to *retype* the command (do not copy/paste).

Comment: @iRon, retyping and got this-> The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying
credentials.

Comment: Ok, that is a complete different message suggesting that I was right and the credentials aren't the issue... Or?

Comment: Conclusion: use the answer from [**@Daniel**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) and watchout for [unicode characters as e.g. em-dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/1701026) (note that your PowerShell version `Windows PowerShell` vs. `PowerShell Core` is also at stake here.)

Answer (score 1):

To keep it somewhat simple, to copy to a folder share which requires different credentials to access you can use `New-PSDrive` to map a drive using those credentials

```
$desiredMappedDrive = 'J'
$desiredMappedDrivePath = '\\10.10.X.X\c$' # Map to administrative C: drive share requires administrator credentials)

$source = 'D:\Test.txt'
$destination = "${desiredMappedDrive}:\temp" 

# Get-Credential cmdlet will request that you enter a username and password that has access to the share
New-PSDrive -Name $desiredMappedDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $desiredMappedDrivePath -Credential (Get-Credential)

# after drive is mapped copy file over
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Verbose
```

Comment: the error shows: New-PSDrive : The network path was not found

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole different approach using `PSSession` no need to map any drives:

```
$targetComputerName = "127.0.0.1"
$Session = New-PSSession $targetComputerName -Credential 'username'
$DestinationPath = "C:\temp"
$source = 'D:\Test.txt'

Copy-Item -Path $source -ToSession $Session -Destination $DestinationPath
$Session | Remove-PSSession
```

If you want to execute it as a script you would have to create a `[SecureString]` and build a credential object.